# Should Ceiling Cat be stopped?

Tags: discussion, chat

Does [Ceiling Cat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-238/ceiling-cat) still add value to the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) or should it be stopped?

When we first launched there was more activity in the chat room, and in the discussion [Should we have a beta new question feed in chat?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/545/should-we-have-a-beta-new-question-feed-in-chat) it was started.  I wonder though if it still adds value.  Trying to find the last time a person posted and read the post is painful.

Should Ceiling Cat be stopped?

Comment: Good question. Chat may indeed die without ceiling cat. I need to think about this. Chat is quiet isn't it? lol* understatement*

Comment: I sometimes look at the chat transcript to get a quick overview of recent new questions.  Not that I'm overly active or anything, but...

Comment: Wait chats have cat memes? I gotta check it out now

Answer (score 0):

As chat is not active, it think it's better to keep ceiling cat going, so if anyone does want to pop into chat, it doesn't look like a complete ghost town.

It the room becomes active again with regular chat, we can talk about removing ceiling cat then, or possibly just feed meta questions into chat.